# Header and page styling problems

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I need help with the preamble. Here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\ProvidesLanguage{Italian}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% THEOREMS -------------------------------------------------------
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollario}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposizione}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definizione}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Congettura}
\newtheorem{ex}{Esempio}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{oss}[thm]{Osservazione}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\itshape\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[L]{\itshape\bfseries\nouppercase\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

%--CHANGE CHAPTER TITLE------------------------------
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
 {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}
%----------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\sffamily

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\huge{Title}
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-10]

\mainmatter

\part{Part1Name}

\chapter{Chapter1Name}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section11Name}

\lipsum

\section{Section11Name}

\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Chapter2Name}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section21Name}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

How can I have blank pages when they are empty? As you can see pages ii,iv,viii,6 are not blank. I'd like them to be blank but without altering the numeration.

Furthermore pages vi and vii have the wrong name on top (it should be "Introduction").

Is there also a way to have the number of the page on the top-left in the left pages and on the top-right in the right pages of the book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your preamble includes a lot of packages that aren't relevant to the problem (or rather: the three problems) at hand, but your example *does* show those problems. So here are the answers:

1. Load the `emptypage` package.
2. Add `\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}` immediately after `\chapter*{Introduction}`. (Alternatively, you could simply use `\chapter{Introduction}` -- this will cause a ToC entry for the introduction, but -- as it is located in the `\frontmatter` -- *won't* turn on chapter numbering.)
3. Specify different settings for even and odd pages in the optional argument of `\fancyhead`.

Other notes:

- The `\cleardoublepage` before `\tableofcontents` is superfluous.
- The preferred way to switch to sans-serif as main font is to add `\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` in the preamble.

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\itshape\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape\bfseries\nouppercase\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\huge{Title}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-10]

\mainmatter

\part{Part1Name}

\chapter{Chapter1Name}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section11Name}

\lipsum

\section{Section11Name}

\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Chapter2Name}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section21Name}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Three-in-one question with non-minimal working example -- http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/should-we-answer-really-bad-questions ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, now it works. I knew some packages were not relevant but I left them because I didn't know if the problem was due to some conflit among them.

Comment: @doncherry Three questions and non-minimal: true. But it is a *working* example, which sadly isn't true for a lot of other questions.

Comment: @lockstep Implying that we're lowering our standards?

Comment: @doncherry Perhaps implying that we don't raise them.

Comment: @doncherry I am sorry, I am not an expert of latex and I was afraid that a working solution for a minimal example could not work for my real situation, so I left all the packages and declarations I was using. Now that I know it is not the case I can edit my question if you want and leave only the relevant packages.

Comment: @Emmet I don't think that's necessary. Note, however, that trying to remove as many packages as possible is a good idea in general -- in your case, you'd have noticed that the problems are *still there* with a minimal preamble. Also note that you should ask only about one issue per question.

Answer (score 1):

Put the command `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the pages that shall be left blank.